# Multi thread running simultaneously

Tags: java, multithreading

My task was to allow users to enter a range of numbers for eg 1-20, user can then enter the number of threads they prefer , and based on the number of threads for eg 5, assign the numbers equally to the number of threads, so in this case  1+2 , 3+4 will be in thread1 , 5+6, 7+8 will be in thread 2 , 9+10, 11 +12 will be in thread 3 and so on. My only problem here is that, my threads does not run simultaneously , thread2 only runs after thread 1 and thread3 runs after thread2, what changes do i have to make so that all threads can run at the same time without waiting for the other to finish?

```
package MyThread;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class MyThread{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         int start,end,threadNo;
         int noOfDigits = 0;
         int arr[]= new int [100];
         System.out.println("Please enter a start number");
         Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
         start = s.nextInt();
         System.out.println("Please enter an end number");
         end = s.nextInt();

     for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        noOfDigits =i;
     }

    System.out.println("Number of digits = " +noOfDigits);
    System.out.println("Enter number of threads divisible by " +noOfDigits);
    threadNo = s.nextInt();

    for (int i=0; i<threadNo; i++) 
        {  
        if (noOfDigits%threadNo==0){
          MultithreadingSum object = new  MultithreadingSum(start,end,threadNo,noOfDigits);
            int total = object.run(i*(end/threadNo)); //sending a parameter to run()
            arr[i] = total; 
            int sum = Arrays.stream(arr).sum();
            System.out.println("Sum of all threads = " +sum);
        }else
   {
       System.out.println(+noOfDigits+ " is not divisible by " +threadNo);
   }
}  
}
} 

 class MultithreadingSum extends Thread{
         int i,j,n,d;
         int a = 0;
     MultithreadingSum(int start, int end, int threadNo,int noOfDigits)
     {
         i = start;
         j = end; 
         n = threadNo;
         d = noOfDigits;
     }

    public int run(int time) 
    {   
       int total =0;
       System.out.println("Thread executed");
       for(a = i + time; a <= j/n+time ; a++){
       System.out.println( +a + "");
       total+=a;
       try {
           sleep(100);
       } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(MultithreadingSum.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }
   }
   System.out.println(getName() + " total sum is "+ total);
   return total;
}
}
```

**OUTPUT, my threads are in order, not working simultaneously**

```
Please enter a start number
1
Please enter an end number
20
Number of digits = 20
Enter number of threads divisible by 20
10
Thread executed
1
2
Thread-0 total sum is 3
Sum of all threads = 3
Thread executed
3
4
Thread-1 total sum is 7
Sum of all threads = 10
Thread executed
5
6
Thread-2 total sum is 11
Sum of all threads = 21
Thread executed
7
8
Thread-3 total sum is 15
Sum of all threads = 36
Thread executed
9
10
Thread-4 total sum is 19
Sum of all threads = 55
Thread executed
11
12
Thread-5 total sum is 23
Sum of all threads = 78
Thread executed
13
14
Thread-6 total sum is 27
Sum of all threads = 105
Thread executed
15
16
Thread-7 total sum is 31
Sum of all threads = 136
Thread executed
17
18
Thread-8 total sum is 35
Sum of all threads = 171
Thread executed
19
20
Thread-9 total sum is 39
```

Comment: the `run` method from `Thread` takes no arguments - you simply created a new method in your `MultithreadingSum` - this is overloading not overriding. And you do not `start` your Threads anywhere - to start a `Thread` you have to call `start` - not `run`.

Comment: I would add that for threads, we normally implement Runnable instead of extending Thread.  We're not really changing the behavior of a Thread, but actually implementing the behavior of Runnable.